# trying to `call` three methods but not working correctly with jQuery map

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Update #1**
I forgot to pass the current object as the first paremeter; see K's answer

---

I have the following methods that are on a google maps. The methods work fine like this:

```
arc.pLocations(ne, sw,m);
arc.pLikedLocations(ne, sw, m);
arc.pLikedItems(ne, sw, m);
```

However, I'd like to have them in an array like this that I can subsequetnly call but this isn't working (I'd be the first acknowledge this is an issue with me):

```
var selected_methods=[arc.pLocations,arc.pLikedLocations,arc.pLikedItems];

// Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Ri> has no method 'lng'  - this is for a variable called sw in pLikedLocations 
$.map(selected_methods, function(val, i){
    console.log("here is index:" + i);
    val.call(ne,sw,m);
});
```

trying to wrap this with another closure but this also isn't working

```
$.map(selected_methods, (function(val, i){
  console.log("here is index:" + i);
  val.call(ne,sw,m);
})(val,i)); // Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined on this line!
```

I have the following I'm doing something really simple wrong. Can anyone spot the issue and help me? It's saturday nigth and I want to be done with this.

thx in advance

Comment: I'm avoiding the issue, but why are you using `map`?  It's only needed when you want the results to be returned as an array, and you're not storing the result of map.  Do you get the same issue if you use `each`, like: `$.each(selected_methods, function() { this.call(arc, ne, sw, m)});`?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: Yes they will as they're using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) incorrectly.

Comment: @muistooshort I noticed that once I read Khanh TO's answer.  Fixed my comment reflecting that.

Comment: I'll edit question to reflect just a misuse of call since I can't delete

Comment: Why delete it?  Just wait a while, and give Khanh the accept.  It might help someone at some point.

Comment: sounds good @ScottMermelstein just updated so that a user can see the issue before reading all if they stumble upon it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the wrong context to the `call` function. Actually, you miss it. Try this:

```
var selected_methods=[arc.pLocations,arc.pLikedLocations,arc.pLikedItems];

$.map(selected_methods, function(val, i){
    console.log("here is index:" + i);
    val.call(arc,ne,sw,m); //Notice the arc
});
```

Comment: You could also `$.each(names, function(m) { arc[m](ne, sw, m) })` if you had just the method names in `names` or you could `$.each(selected_methods, function(f) { f(ne, se, m) })` if the methods were really just functions that didn't care about what `this` was.

Comment: thx @muistooshort this also worked, I had to add a value in the each for the index, value of `each` not sure if this is jQuery 2.0 behavior http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/; though it was like ruby but thx for answer as this is what I went with. Very MUCH appreciated

Comment: @timpone: Right, I had the `$.each` callback arguments mixed up, `$.each` sends in the index first and the actual element second.