# how to add an argument to a method stored in an array that is called later

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow-up to this question (although this is self-contained) [trying to `call` three methods but not working correctly with jQuery map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425747/trying-to-call-three-methods-but-not-working-correctly-with-jquery-map).

I am trying to store a set of methods in an array but there is a set that might have arguments like below (the initial methods are in before_methods and the proposed methods are in lm_methods). I'm sure it's pretty self explanatory what I want but I'd like to be able to merge in the arguments into a reasonable call to f (specifically the arc.pLikedByTerm). I currently have the following:

```
// signature
pLikedByTerm:function(term, ne, sw, m){
   ....  
}

// code before_methods just to show
this.before_methods=[arc.pLocations,arc.pLikedLocations,arc.pLikedItems];
this.lm_methods=[arc.pLocations,arc.pLikedLocations,arc.pLikedItems, arc.pLikedByTerm('surfing'),arc.pLikedByTerm('sailing')];
$.each(this.lm_methods, function(i,f){
  f(ne,sw,m);
});
```

How would I do this or is this bad design? What would be the idiomatic way? My brain is fried.

thx in advance

**Update 1**

Playing around with answer below, it looks like this works which might the simplest things:

```
var fns=[logStuff("this is msg"), logMoreArgs("a term","a you msg")];

for (var i=0; i<fns.length; i++) {
  fns[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having an array of functions is common practice when used often.  For example, consider this Callback class.

```
function Callback(){
    this.callbacks = [];
}

Callback.prototype.run = function(cb) {
    for (var i=0; i<this.callbacks.length; i++) {
        this.callbacks[i]();
    }
};
```

We can then add some callbacks.

```
function logStuff(msg) {
    jsprint(msg || "No message");
}

obj = new Callback();
obj.callbacks.push(logStuff);
obj.callbacks.push(logStuff);
obj.run();
```

If we [run this](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ7k6/) we see that it's only logging our default value.  So if we want to bind some data, we can use the bind function.

> ### [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
>
> **thisArg**
>   The value to be passed as the this parameter to the target
>   function when the bound function is called. The value is ignored if
>   the bound function is constructed using the new operator.
>
> **arg1, arg2, ...**
>   Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the bound function
>   when invoking the target function.

Our new code sets the first parameter to different strings, which we then see.  You can bind any number of parameters.

```
obj = new Callback();
obj.callbacks.push(logStuff.bind(null, "My message"));
obj.callbacks.push(logStuff.bind(null, "My other message"));
obj.run();
```

### [end result](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ7k6/1/)

Comment: thx, thinking through this and using your example, I updated the question with a sol'n that will work for me and doesn't need to get into bind. Would this also work (the original question was probably phrased poorly on my end - Sat night at midnight will do that).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing would work just ok. Just remove the arguments and parens:

Instead of:

> this.lm_methods=[arc.pLocations,arc.pLikedLocations,arc.pLikedItems,
>   arc.pLikedByTerm('surfing'),arc.pLikedByTerm('sailing')];

Do:

> this.lm_methods=[arc.pLocations,arc.pLikedLocations,arc.pLikedItems,
>   arc.pLikedByTerm,arc.pLikedByTerm];

Example:

```
        function say(txt) {
            console.log("say" + txt);
        }
        function shout(txt) {
            console.log("shout" + txt);
        }
        function whisper(txt) {
            console.log("whisper" + txt);
        }

    var funcArr = [say, shout, whisper];

    $.each(funcArr, function(i, f) {
        f("hello");
    });
```

would print:

sayhello 
shouthello 
whisperhello